# Arch linux: Cura thows: ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name

Tags: arch-linux, python, pacman, pip

when i type `cura` to my terminal I get this error and program does not start:

```
john@arch-thinkpad ~> cura
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/UM/PluginRegistry.py:4: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/UM/Settings/InstanceContainer.py:53: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
  version_regex = re.compile("\nversion ?= ?(\d+)")
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/UM/Settings/InstanceContainer.py:55: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \w
  type_regex = re.compile("\ntype ?= ?(\w+)")
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/UM/VersionUpgradeManager.py:98: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \.
  ".*\.lock",       # Don't upgrade the configuration file lock. It's not persistent.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cura/CuraApplication.py", line 57, in <module>
    from cura.Arranging.ArrangeObjectsJob import ArrangeObjectsJob
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cura/Arranging/ArrangeObjectsJob.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cura.Arranging.Nest2DArrange import arrange
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cura/Arranging/Nest2DArrange.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pynest2d import Point, Box, Item, NfpConfig, nest
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cura", line 187, in <module>
    from cura.CuraApplication import CuraApplication
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cura/CuraApplication.py", line 57, in <module>
    from cura.Arranging.ArrangeObjectsJob import ArrangeObjectsJob
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cura/Arranging/ArrangeObjectsJob.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cura.Arranging.Nest2DArrange import arrange
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cura/Arranging/Nest2DArrange.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pynest2d import Point, Box, Item, NfpConfig, nest
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

What can I do to fix this ? I already tried to update all pip packages but error remains.

thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution was to uninstall cura with dependencies:

```
sudo pacman -Rns cura
```

and install it again:

```
sudo pacman -S cura
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to build pynest2d from master? It worked for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/Ultimaker/pynest2d
cd pynest2d
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ../
make
sudo make install
```